# PayPal API integration with Django

Tags: django, paypal, payment-gateway

I am integrating PayPal API with Django back-end (Reactcjs for front-end) in my  project with the help of sandbox accounts (@business & @personal account). What I did till now is I  have a client_id and a secret used for generating access_token from paypal.

```
import requests
import base64
def PaypalToken(client_ID, client_Secret):
```

`` url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
    data = {
                "client_id":client_ID,
                "client_secret":client_Secret,
                "grant_type":"client_credentials"
            }
    headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization": "Basic {0}".format(base64.b64encode((client_ID + ":" + client_Secret).encode()).decode())
            }

    token = requests.post(url, data, headers=headers)
    return token

x = PaypalToken(my_client_ID, my_client_Secret)
print(x.text)
<code>
This gonna provide me a token then I use that token to post json object on paypal.
<pre>
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": 'Bearer' + token}
url = https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders
data = '{
                "intent": "CAPTURE",
                "application_context": {
                    "return_url": "https://www.example.com",
                    "cancel_url": "https://www.example.com",
                    "brand_name": "EXAMPLE INC",
                    "landing_page": "BILLING",
                    "shipping_preference": "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS",
                    "user_action": "CONTINUE"
                },
                "purchase_units": [
                    {
                        "reference_id": "PUHF",
                        "description": "Sporting Goods",

                        "custom_id": "CUST-HighFashions",
                        "soft_descriptor": "HighFashions",
                        "amount": {
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                            "value": "220.00",
                            "breakdown": {
                                "item_total": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "180.00"
                                },
                                "shipping": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "20.00"
                                },
                                "handling": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "10.00"
                                },
                                "tax_total": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "20.00"
                                },
                                "shipping_discount": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "10"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "name": "T-Shirt",
                                "description": "Green XL",
                                "sku": "sku01",
                                "unit_amount": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "90.00"
                                },
                                "tax": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "10.00"
                                },
                                "quantity": "1",
                                "category": "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Shoes",
                                "description": "Running, Size 10.5",
                                "sku": "sku02",
                                "unit_amount": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "45.00"
                                },
                                "tax": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "5.00"
                                },
                                "quantity": "2",
                                "category": "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                            }
                        ],
                        "shipping": {
                            "method": "United States Postal Service",
                            "name": {`enter code here`
                                "full_name":"John Doe"
                            },
                            "address": {
                                "address_line_1": "123 Townsend St",
                                "address_line_2": "Floor 6",
                                "admin_area_2": "San Francisco",
                                "admin_area_1": "CA",
                                "postal_code": "94107",
                                "country_code": "US"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }'
result = requests.post(url, data, headers=header)

<code>

this gonna give me 4 links 
<pre>

{
  "id": "5O190127TN364715T",
  "status": "CREATED",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5O190127TN364715T",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=5O190127TN364715T",
      "rel": "approve",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5O190127TN364715T/capture",
      "rel": "capture",
      "method": "POST"
    }
  ]
}

<code> ``

What Next ?

Answer (score 0):

First, implement two routes that return only JSON data. One for creating the order and one for capturing it after approval.

For the interim payer approval step, ignore those 4 links which are for old integration patterns that redirect away from your site. In place of that, use the PayPal JS SDK for in-context approval (keeping your site loaded in the background) and have it fetch from those two routes on your server.

Here's the approval flow in pure JS: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

For the same with react, see [@paypal/react-papal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js) and its [storybook examples](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default).